# Add Query Params to Current Url in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react router 4 and when some checkboxes are checked I want to update the current url with the values from the checkbox.

How can I push parameters to the current url? Also if possible I don't really want to support it that if they click the back button it would uncheck the last option (unless I pretty much get this functionality for free).

So I am thinking it would have to be more a replacement of the url rather that push.

Answer (score 2):

Install `history` package from npm

Create a new file **config/history.js**

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
export default createHistory();
```

Now in your code where you wanted to update the url, use the following:

```
import history from './config/history';

....
<input type="checkbox" onChange={() => history.push('/foo?variable=value') } />
```

Comment: `history.replace(url)` seems to better fit the question (instead of `history.push(url))`